# Docker Entrypoint for Postgres 9.3

Tags: postgresql, docker, postgis

This is my Dockerfile for installing Postgres.

```
# Set the base image to Ubuntu
FROM ubuntu:14.04

# Update the repository sources list
RUN apt-get update -y

################## BEGIN INSTALLATION ######################
# Install wget
RUN apt-get install wget -y

# Setup Postgres repository
RUN wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc 
| sudo apt-key add -

# Add Postgres repository
RUN sh -c "echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/  trusty-pgdg main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/postgresql.list"

# Update repository
RUN apt-get update -y

# Install Postgres with Postgis
RUN apt-get install postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1 -y
```

How can i add an Entrypoint for Postgres so that Postgres is automatically started in a Docker-container

Answer (score 1):

My solution to start Postgres automatic:

```
RUN chmod +x /etc/init.d/postgresql
CMD service postgresql start && tail -F /var/lib/postgresql/data/serverlog
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take ideas from the official [docker-library/postgres `Dockerfile`](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/04b1d366d51a942b88fff6c62943f92c7c38d9b6/9.3/Dockerfile):

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE 5432
CMD ["postgres"]
```

They use a [`docker-entrypoint.sh`](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/04b1d366d51a942b88fff6c62943f92c7c38d9b6/9.3/docker-entrypoint.sh) script which will, at the end, launch postgres

```
exec gosu postgres "$@"
```

Comment: is there not a easier way like this: ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/postgres/start.sh", "run"] to start Postgres?

Comment: @FredBongers Sure: I am simply pointing out that there can be *a lot* to do before starting postgres, as the `docker-entrypoint.sh` illustrates (https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/04b1d366d51a942b88fff6c62943f92c7c38d9b6/9.3/docker-entrypoint.sh). I would not ignore that initialization step.

Comment: Thanks if have now a solution